# Why doesn't this function "take" after I iterrows over a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with timestamped temperature and wind speed values, and a function to convert those into a "wind chill." I'm using iterrows to run the function on each row, and hoping to get a DataFrame out with a nifty "Wind Chill" column.

However, while it seems to work as it's going through, and has actually "worked" at least once, I can't seem to replicate it consistently. I feel like it's something I'm missing about the structure of DataFrames, in general, but I'm hoping someone can help.

```
In [28]: bigdf.head()
Out[28]: 


                           Day  Temperature  Wind Speed  Year
2003-03-01 06:00:00-05:00  1    30.27        5.27        2003
2003-03-01 07:00:00-05:00  1    30.21        4.83        2003
2003-03-01 08:00:00-05:00  1    31.81        6.09        2003
2003-03-01 09:00:00-05:00  1    34.04        6.61        2003
2003-03-01 10:00:00-05:00  1    35.31        6.97        2003
```

So I add a 'Wind Chill' column to `bigdf` and prepopulate with `NaN`.

```
In [29]: bigdf['Wind Chill'] = NaN
```

Then I try to iterate over the rows, to add the actual Wind Chills.

```
In [30]: for row_index, row in bigdf[:5].iterrows():
    ...:     row['Wind Chill'] = windchill(row['Temperature'], row['Wind Speed'])
    ...:     print row['Wind Chill']
    ...:
24.7945889994
25.1365267133
25.934114012
28.2194307516
29.5051046953
```

As you can say, the new values *appear* to be applied to the 'Wind Chill' column. Here's the `windchill` function, just in case that helps:

```
def windchill(temp, wind):
    if temp>50 or wind<=3:
        return temp
    else:
        return 35.74 + 0.6215*temp - 35.75*wind**0.16 + 0.4275*temp*wind**0.16
```

But, when I look at the DataFrame again, the NaN's are still there:

```
In [31]: bigdf.head()
Out[31]: 

                           Day  Temperature  Wind Speed  Year  Wind Chill
2003-03-01 06:00:00-05:00  1    30.27        5.27        2003  NaN
2003-03-01 07:00:00-05:00  1    30.21        4.83        2003  NaN
2003-03-01 08:00:00-05:00  1    31.81        6.09        2003  NaN
2003-03-01 09:00:00-05:00  1    34.04        6.61        2003  NaN
2003-03-01 10:00:00-05:00  1    35.31        6.97        2003  NaN
```

What's even weirder is that it **has** worked once or twice, and I can't tell what I did differently.

I must admit I'm not especially familiar with the inner workings of pandas, and get confused with indexing, etc., so I feel like I'm probably missing something very basic here (or doing this the hard way).

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to do this:

```
In [11]: df.apply(lambda row: windchill(row['Temperature'], row['Wind Speed']),
                 axis=1)
Out[11]:
2003-03-01 06:00:00-05:00    24.794589
2003-03-01 07:00:00-05:00    25.136527
2003-03-01 08:00:00-05:00    25.934114
2003-03-01 09:00:00-05:00    28.219431
2003-03-01 10:00:00-05:00    29.505105

In [12]: df['Wind Chill'] = df.apply(lambda row: windchill(row['Temperature'], row['Wind Speed']),
                                    axis=1)

In [13]: df
Out[13]:
                           Day  Temperature  Wind Speed  Year  Wind Chill
2003-03-01 06:00:00-05:00    1        30.27        5.27  2003   24.794589
2003-03-01 07:00:00-05:00    1        30.21        4.83  2003   25.136527
2003-03-01 08:00:00-05:00    1        31.81        6.09  2003   25.934114
2003-03-01 09:00:00-05:00    1        34.04        6.61  2003   28.219431
2003-03-01 10:00:00-05:00    1        35.31        6.97  2003   29.505105
```

.

To expand on the reason for your confusion, I think it stems from the fact that the row variables are **[*copies* rather than *views*](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy) of the df**, so changes don't propagate:

```
In [21]: for _, row in df.iterrows(): row['Day'] = 2
```

We see that it is making the change **successfully to the copy**, the `row` variable(s):

```
In [22]: row
Out[22]:
Day               2.00
Temperature      35.31
Wind Speed        6.97
Year           2003.00
Name: 2003-03-01 10:00:00-05:00
```

Bu they don't update to the DataFrame:

```
In [23]: df
Out[23]:
                           Day  Temperature  Wind Speed  Year
2003-03-01 06:00:00-05:00    1        30.27        5.27  2003
2003-03-01 07:00:00-05:00    1        30.21        4.83  2003
2003-03-01 08:00:00-05:00    1        31.81        6.09  2003
2003-03-01 09:00:00-05:00    1        34.04        6.61  2003
2003-03-01 10:00:00-05:00    1        35.31        6.97  2003
```

The following also leaves `df` unchanged:

```
In [24]: row = df.ix[0]  # also a copy

In [25]: row['Day'] = 2
```

Whereas if we do take a **view**: (we'll see a *change* `df`.)

```
In [26]: row = df.ix[2:3]  # this one's a view

In [27]: row['Day'] = 3
```

See [Returning a view versus a copy (in the docs)](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy).

Comment: I suspected it had something to do with copies vs views, but I was thinking about it the opposite way and really confusing myself. Thanks for the detailed answer!

Comment: I had a similar problem, with a similar solution, but here's the weird part: It WORKED on an older installation somehow, but not with newer versions of Pandas on other machines. That REALLY drove me nuts. So in case anyone else starts pulling their hair out on a similar problem, I thought I'd pass this along

Comment: @ViennaMike are you saying the above worked on newer or older pandas? There are a few edge cases in pandas' apply which have been tweaked over last few releases so this could be one of them!

Comment: @AndyHayden, yes, I was using an older version of Anaconda which had a version 11, I believe, edition of Pandas, and was using iterrows, and the way I had it coded worked fine, with references to updates in the original data frame via row. But that didn't work (apparently row referenced a copy, not the original) when I tried on two later versions. Fixed it in my code with direct .loc references to the original dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

Try it with:

```
bigdf['Wind Chill'] = bigdf.apply(lambda x: windchill(x['Temperature'], x['Wind Speed']), axis=1)
```

for the whole DataFrame at once using your simple `windchill` function.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that you don't need any explicit loop. The following hopefully does what you want

```
bigdf = pd.DataFrame({'Temperature': [30.27, 30.21, 31.81], 'Wind Speed': [5.27, 4.83, 6.09]})

def windchill(temp, wind):
    "compute the wind chill given two pandas series temp and wind"
    tomodify = (temp<=50) & (wind>3) #check which values need to be modified
    t = temp.copy()  #create a new series
    # change only the values that need modification
    t[tomodify] = 35.74 + 0.6215*temp[tomodify] - 35.75*wind[tomodify]**0.16 +
        0.4275*temp[tomodify]*wind[tomodify]**0.16
    return t

bigdf['Wind Chill'] = windchill(bigdf['Temperature'], bigdf['Wind Speed'])

bigdf

   Temperature  Wind Speed  Wind Chill
0        30.27        5.27   24.794589
1        30.21        4.83   25.136527
2        31.81        6.09   25.934114
```

ps: this implementation of `windchill` works also with numpy arrays.

Comment: Thanks. My googling revealed that reworking windchill was another option but I was really trying to figure what I was doing wrong the way it was. :)

Comment: Gotcha. Good that you found the explanation

Comment: I had a similar problem, with a similar solution, but here's the weird part: It WORKED on an older installation somehow, but not with newer versions of Pandas on other machines. That REALLY drove me nuts. So in case anyone else starts pulling their hair out on a similar problem, I thought I'd pass this along.