# Python Pandas check if a value occurs more then once in the same day

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe as below. What I am trying to do is check if a station has variable `yyy` and any other variable on the same day (as in the case of `station1`). If this is true I need to delete the whole row containing `yyy`.

Currently I am doing this using `iterrows()` and looping to search the days in which this variable appears, changing the variable to something like "delete me", building a new dataframe from this (because [pandas doesn't support replacing in place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15972264/why-doesnt-this-function-take-after-i-iterrows-over-a-pandas-dataframe)) and filtering the new dataframe to get rid of the unwanted rows. This works now because my dataframes are small, but is not likely to scale.

**Question:** This seems like a very "non-Pandas" way to do this, is there some other method of deleting out the unwanted variables?

```
                dateuse         station         variable1
0   2012-08-12 00:00:00        station1               xxx
1   2012-08-12 00:00:00        station1               yyy
2   2012-08-23 00:00:00        station2               aaa
3   2012-08-23 00:00:00        station3               bbb
4   2012-08-25 00:00:00        station4               ccc
5   2012-08-25 00:00:00        station4               ccc
6   2012-08-25 00:00:00        station4               ccc
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I might index using a boolean array.  We want to delete rows (if I understand what you're after, anyway!) which have `yyy` and more than one `dateuse`/`station` combination.

We can use `transform` to broadcast the size of each `dateuse`/`station` combination up to the length of the dataframe, and then select the rows in groups which have length > 1.  Then we can `&` this with where the `yyy`s are.

```
>>> multiple = df.groupby(["dateuse", "station"])["variable1"].transform(len) > 1
>>> must_be_isolated = df["variable1"] == "yyy"
>>> df[~(multiple & must_be_isolated)]
               dateuse   station variable1
0  2012-08-12 00:00:00  station1       xxx
2  2012-08-23 00:00:00  station2       aaa
3  2012-08-23 00:00:00  station3       bbb
4  2012-08-25 00:00:00  station4       ccc
5  2012-08-25 00:00:00  station4       ccc
6  2012-08-25 00:00:00  station4       ccc
```

Comment: This works, but I'm exactly sure why... Especially what does `df[~(multiple & must_be_isolated)]` do?

Comment: `print multiple` will show that it's a boolean array which is `True` whenever the row is a member of a `(dateuse, station`) group with length `> 1`.  `must_be_isolated` is simply an array which is True whenever `variable1 == 'yyy'`.  `multiple & must_be_isolated` is a booolean array which is `True` whenever there's something we want to be alone (here, `yyy`) which is in a group with more than one member.   Those are the rows we want to remove.  `~(mul.. & must_..)` is the negation of that, the rows we want to keep.  `df[some_boolean_array_here]` selects those rows.  Does that make sense?