# Updating a value in a pandas dataframe in an iterrows loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, loops

I am doing some geocoding work that I used `selenium` to screen scrape the x-y coordinate I need for address of a location, I imported an xls file to pandas dataframe and want to use an explicit loop to update the rows which do not have the x-y coordinate, like below:

```py
for index, row in rche_df.iterrows():
    if isinstance(row.wgs1984_latitude, float):
        row = row.copy()
        target = row.address_chi
        dict_temp = geocoding(target)
        row.wgs1984_latitude = dict_temp['lat']
        row.wgs1984_longitude = dict_temp['long']
```

I have read [Why doesn't this function "take" after I iterrows over a pandas DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15972264/why-doesnt-this-function-take-after-i-iterrows-over-a-pandas-dataframe) and am fully aware that `iterrows` only gives us a view rather than a copy for editing, but what if I really to update the value row by row? Is `lambda` feasible?

Comment: I *think*  you can do `rche_df.loc[index, 'wgs1984_latitude'] = dict_temp['lat']`, i.e. use the index to get at the right section of the original dataframe. Let me know if that doesn't work and I'll try work up a proper answer.

Comment: @Marius looks like it is working, thanks, another alternative is to convert the dataframe into dict and use ordinary for-loop to do the modification

Comment: This answer did not work for me (why on Earth not...), but this did: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23330654/update-a-dataframe-in-pandas-while-iterating-row-by-row/29262040?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 223, accepted):

The rows you get back from `iterrows` are copies that are no longer connected to the original data frame, so edits don't change your dataframe. Thankfully, because each item you get back from `iterrows` contains the current index, you can use that to access and edit the relevant row of the dataframe:

```
for index, row in rche_df.iterrows():
    if isinstance(row.wgs1984_latitude, float):
        row = row.copy()
        target = row.address_chi        
        dict_temp = geocoding(target)
        rche_df.loc[index, 'wgs1984_latitude'] = dict_temp['lat']
        rche_df.loc[index, 'wgs1984_longitude'] = dict_temp['long']
```

In my experience, this approach seems slower than using an approach like `apply` or `map`, but as always, it's up to you to decide how to make the performance/ease of coding tradeoff.

Comment: This is not strictly true, they may not be copies. Specifically if the dtype is the same for all cols

Comment: This gave a copy warning for me.  Ended up using: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33518124/how-to-apply-a-function-on-every-row-on-a-dataframe

Comment: Don't you get the index back anyway? See @jpp's answer to [Pandas for loop over dataframe gives too many values to unpack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50243204/575530). The error I get from the code in this answer is `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

Comment: I found that I had to run `df = df.reset_index()` to get this working without an index error because I had chopped and sliced my dataframe.

Answer (score 11):

Another way based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23330654/8961642):

```
for index, row in rche_df.iterrows():
    if isinstance(row.wgs1984_latitude, float):
        row = row.copy()
        target = row.address_chi        
        dict_temp = geocoding(target)
        
        rche_df.at[index, 'wgs1984_latitude'] = dict_temp['lat']
        rche_df.at[index, 'wgs1984_longitude'] = dict_temp['long']
```

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37216485/8961642) describe difference between `.loc` and `.at`. Shortly, `.at` faster than `.loc`.

Answer (score 2):

##### 1. Use `itertuples()` instead

Pandas DataFrames are really a collection of columns/Series objects (e.g. `for x in df` iterates over the column labels), so even if a loop where to be implemented, it's better if the loop over across columns. `iterrows()` is anti-pattern to that "native" pandas behavior because it creates a Series for each row, which slows down code so much. A better/faster option is to use `itertuples()`. It creates namedtuples of each row that you can access either by index or column label. There's almost no modification to the code in the OP to apply it.

Also (as @Alireza Mazochi mentioned), to assign a value to a single cell, `at` is faster than `loc`.

```py
for row in rche_df.itertuples():
#                  ^^^^^^^^^^   <------ `itertuples` instead of `iterrows`
    if isinstance(row.wgs1984_latitude, float):
        target = row.address_chi
        dict_temp = geocoding(target)
        rche_df.at[row.Index, 'wgs1984_latitude'] = dict_temp['lat']
        rche_df.at[row.Index, 'wgs1984_longitude'] = dict_temp['long']
        #       ^^ ^^^^^^^^^  <---- `at` instead of `loc` for faster assignment
        #                           `row.Index` is the row's index, can also use `row[0]`
```

As you can see, using `itertuples()` is almost the same syntax as using `iterrows()`, yet it's over 6 times faster (you can verify it with a simple `timeit` test).

##### 2. `to_dict()` is also an option

One drawback of `itertuples()` is that whenever there's a space in a column label (e.g. `'Col A'` etc.), it will be mangled when converted into a namedtuple, so e.g. if `'address_chi'` was `'address chi'`, it will not be possible to access it via `row.address chi`. One way to solve this problem is to convert the DataFrame into a dictionary and iterate over it.

Again, the syntax is almost the same as the one used for `iterrows()`.

```py
for index, row in rche_df.to_dict('index').items():
#                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  <---- convert to a dict
    if isinstance(row['wgs1984_latitude'], float):
        target = row['address_chi']
        dict_temp = geocoding(target)
        rche_df.at[index, 'wgs1984_latitude'] = dict_temp['lat']
        rche_df.at[index, 'wgs1984_longitude'] = dict_temp['long']
```

This method is also about 6 times faster than `iterrows()` but slightly slower than `itertuples()` (also it's more memory-intensive than `itertuples()` because it creates an explicit dictionary whereas `itertuples()` creates a generator).

##### 3. Iterate over only the necessary column/rows

The main bottleneck in the particular code in the OP (and in general, why a loop is sometimes necessary in a pandas dataframe) is that the function `geocoding()` is not vectorized. So one way to make the code much faster is to call it only on the relevant column (`'address_chi'`) and on the relevant rows (filtered using a boolean mask).

Note that creating the boolean mask was necessary only because there was an if-clause in the original code. If a conditional check was not needed, the boolean mask is not needed, so the necessary loop boils down to a single loop over a particular column (`address_chi`).

```py
# boolean mask to filter only the relevant rows
# this is analogous to if-clause in the loop in the OP
msk = [isinstance(row, float) for row in rche_df['wgs1984_latitude'].tolist()]

# call geocoding on the relevant values 
# (filtered using the boolean mask built above) 
# in the address_chi column
# and create a nested list
out = []
for target in rche_df.loc[msk, 'address_chi'].tolist():
    dict_temp = geocoding(target)
    out.append([dict_temp['lat'], dict_temp['long']])

# assign the nested list to the relevant rows of the original frame
rche_df.loc[msk, ['wgs1984_latitude', 'wgs1984_longitude']] = out
```

This method is about 40 times faster than `iterrows()`.

---

##### A working example and performance test

```py
def geocoding(x):
    return {'lat': x*2, 'long': x*2}


def iterrows_(df):
    
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if isinstance(row.wgs1984_latitude, float):
            target = row.address_chi        
            dict_temp = geocoding(target)
            df.at[index, 'wgs1984_latitude'] = dict_temp['lat']
            df.at[index, 'wgs1984_longitude'] = dict_temp['long']
    
    return df


def itertuples_(df):
    
    for row in df.itertuples():
        if isinstance(row.wgs1984_latitude, float):
            target = row.address_chi
            dict_temp = geocoding(target)
            df.at[row.Index, 'wgs1984_latitude'] = dict_temp['lat']
            df.at[row.Index, 'wgs1984_longitude'] = dict_temp['long']
        
    return df


def to_dict_(df):
    
    for index, row in df.to_dict('index').items():
        if isinstance(row['wgs1984_latitude'], float):
            target = row['address_chi']
            dict_temp = geocoding(target)
            df.at[index, 'wgs1984_latitude'] = dict_temp['lat']
            df.at[index, 'wgs1984_longitude'] = dict_temp['long']
            
    return df


def boolean_mask_loop(df):

    msk = [isinstance(row, float) for row in df['wgs1984_latitude'].tolist()]

    out = []
    for target in df.loc[msk, 'address_chi'].tolist():
        dict_temp = geocoding(target)
        out.append([dict_temp['lat'], dict_temp['long']])

    df.loc[msk, ['wgs1984_latitude', 'wgs1984_longitude']] = out
    
    return df


df = pd.DataFrame({'address_chi': range(20000)})
df['wgs1984_latitude'] = pd.Series([x if x%2 else float('nan') for x in df['address_chi'].tolist()], dtype=object)


%timeit itertuples_(df.copy())
# 248 ms ± 12.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit boolean_mask_loop(df.copy())
# 38.7 ms ± 1.19 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit to_dict_(df.copy())
# 289 ms ± 10.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit iterrows_(df.copy())
# 1.57 s ± 27.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```