# Create date range list with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I got DataFrame with columns 'start_date' and 'end_date'.

```
    start_date  finish_date
0   2019-06-16  2019-06-23
1   2019-05-29  2019-06-05
2   2019-03-26  2019-03-28
3   2019-04-22  2019-04-24
4   2019-05-08  2019-05-08
```

I want to create a column that will contain a list of months in this range, like this:

```
    start_date  finish_date  range
0   2019-06-16  2019-06-23  [2019-06]
1   2019-05-29  2019-06-05  [2019-05, 2019-06]
2   2019-03-26  2019-03-28  [2019-03]
3   2019-04-22  2019-08-24  [2019-04, 2019-05, 2019-06, 2019-07]
4   2018-12-08  2019-02-08  [2018-12, 2019-01, 2019-02]
```

I tried to use period_range:

```
df['range'] = df.apply(lambda x: pd.period_range(start=df['start_date'], end=df['finish_date'], freq='M'))
```

And something like this, but I got only errors.
Can You, please, help me - is it possible to use period_range/date_range to solve my problem?

Thank You for Your time!

Comment: df['range'] = df.apply(lambda x: pd.period_range(start=x['start_date'], end=x['finish_date'], freq='M'))

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33518725/1609514) explains the method used in @BEN_YO's comment.

Comment: @BEN_YO's answer will work. You are passing x to your lambda function, not the entire df.

Comment: Thank you so, so much!

Comment: @RustemNagimov also add `,axis=1`

Comment: Got it :) Now it works, thank You, Ben!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
df['range'] = pd.Series([pd.date_range(i, j, freq='D').strftime('%Y-%m').unique().to_numpy() 
                         for i, j in zip(df['start_date'], df['finish_date'])])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  start_date finish_date                                          range
0 2019-06-16  2019-06-23                                      [2019-06]
1 2019-05-29  2019-06-05                             [2019-05, 2019-06]
2 2019-03-26  2019-03-28                                      [2019-03]
3 2019-04-22  2019-08-24  [2019-04, 2019-05, 2019-06, 2019-07, 2019-08]
4 2018-12-08  2019-02-08                    [2018-12, 2019-01, 2019-02]
```

Comment: Thank You very much :) It works, but what interesting - the last N rows just have NaN

Comment: Can you create a small dataset that will produce the NaN?