# Find months between dates pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large DataFrame with two columns - start_date and finish_date with dates in string format. f.e. "2018-06-01"
I want to create third column with list of months between two dates.
So, if I have a start_date - "2018-06-01", finish_date - "2018-08-01", in the third column I expect ["2018-06-01", "2018-07-01", "2018-08-01"]. Day doesn't matter for me, so we can delete it.
I find many ways to do it for simple strings, but no one to do it for pandas DataFrame.

Comment: This may help you to find all months. Just in response code instead of `freq='D'`, you should put `freq='M'`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63730078/create-date-range-list-with-pandas

Answer (score 0):

`Pandas` has a function called `apply` which allows you to apply logic to every row of a `dataframe`.

We can use `dateutil` to get all months between the start and end date, then apply the logic to every row of your `dataframe` as a new column.

```
import pandas as pd
import time
import datetime
from dateutil.rrule import rrule, MONTHLY

#Dataframe creation, this is just for the example, use the one you already have created.
data = {'start': datetime.datetime.strptime("10-10-2020", "%d-%m-%Y"), 'end': datetime.datetime.strptime("10-12-2020", "%d-%m-%Y")}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=[0])

#df
#       start        end
#0 2020-10-10 2020-12-10

# Find all months between the start and end date, apply to every row in the dataframe. Result is a list.

df['months'] = df.apply(lambda x: [date.strftime("%m/%Y") for date in rrule(MONTHLY, dtstart=x.start, until=x.end)], axis = 1)

#df
#       start        end                       months
#0 2020-10-10 2020-12-10  [10/2020, 11/2020, 12/2020]
```