# python - interpolation on dataframe values

Tags: python, dataframe, interpolation

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

def interpolate_iv_my(x,y,newX_Value):
    y_interp =  interp1d(x,y)
    iv = y_interp(newX_Value)
    return iv

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'30': [-23, 12, -12, 10, -23, 12, -32, 15, -20, 10],
                   '40': [-30, 20, -21, 15, -33, 22, -40, 25, -22, 12],
                   '50': [-40, 25, -26, 19, -39, 32, -45, 35, -32, 18],
                   '60': [-45, 34, -29, 25, -53, 67, -55, 45, -42, 19],
})

x = [30,40,50,60]
df['x_'] = np.random.choice([35,33,42,52],10).tolist()
```

Picture of the dataframe:

[image]

- I am trying to get a new column with interpolated value corresponding
  to the value in the 'x_' column. for instance for the first row for
  the x value of 52

The interpolated value will be

```
y = [-23,-30,-40,-45]

interpolate_iv_my(x,y,52)

which gives me -41.0
```

What's the best way to do this for all the rows (my dataframe has over 50k rows)?

### Edited

ok came up with this not sure if this is the best solution

```
iter_list = []
for l,r in df.iterrows():
    y = []
    y.append(r['30'])
    y.append(r['40'])
    y.append(r['50'])
    y.append(r['60'])
    iter_list.append(interpolate_iv_my(x,y,r['x_']).tolist())

df ['interpolated'] = iter_list
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Applying function with multiple arguments to create a new pandas column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19914937/applying-function-with-multiple-arguments-to-create-a-new-pandas-column)

Answer (score 0):

**I think your `interpolate_iv_my` function isn't working properly.**

But the correct code for applying function to all rows in a dataframe and creating new column based on those results is this:

```
df['interpolate'] = df.apply(lambda row: interpolate_iv_my(row, x, 52), axis=1)
```

Comment: no I think the function looks fine, I just manually ran interpolation manually on excel for the first three rows and matched the python values

Comment: coming back to the solution you proposed how do I pass the row in my code thats where I am struggling, and I think it should be (x, row, 52) in your code not (row, x, 52)

Comment: Did it work when you swaped it?

Comment: your code doesnt tell me how am I passing the row to the apply function.

Comment: I am sorry but yes it does - it uses lambda function to which it passes the `row` argument. Similar answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33518725/11101156