# Getting Pandas Key Error on Row although the key exists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter

I have a dataframe which consists of the columns 'App', 'Query' and 'Label'

```
train_data = pd.DataFrame({
     'Query':['shoerack','shoerack','shoerack','shoerack', 'nike shoes'], 
     'App':  ['amazon', 'amazon', 'amazon', 'amazon', 'zalando'],
     'Label':[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]})
```

now if I do a simple apply:

```
train_data.apply(lambda row: print(row['App']))
```

I get:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[20], line 4
  1 train_data = pd.DataFrame({'Query': ['shoerack','shoerack','shoerack','shoerack', 'nike shoes'], 
  2                            'App': ['amazon', 'amazon', 'amazon', 'amazon', 'zalando'],
  3                            'Label': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]})
 ----> 4 train_data.apply(lambda row: print(row['App']))
 
KeyError: 'App'
```

According to this: [How to apply a function on every row on a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33518124/how-to-apply-a-function-on-every-row-on-a-dataframe)
the apply should work fine as it is per row. Why do I get a Key Error if the key exists?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you trying to do? I almost never have to use `apply` on `axis=1`

Comment: I am generating a negative sample based on the input line. Therefore I am calling a function per row and passing the query and the app as arguments. I just simplified it with print() to make it easy reproduceable.

Comment: Thanks. Make sure to check whether your function can be vectorized. `apply` should always be avoided whenever possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with the default axis will run on **columns**. The is no `App` indice in your index, thus the `KeyError`.

You need to use `axis=1`:

```
train_data.apply(lambda row: print(row['App']), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
# printed
amazon
amazon
amazon
amazon
zalando

# returned value
0    None
1    None
2    None
3    None
4    None
dtype: object
```