# pandas .at versus .loc

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've been exploring how to optimize my code and ran across `pandas` `.at` method. Per the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.at.html#pandas.DataFrame.at)

> Fast label-based scalar accessor
>
> Similarly to loc, at provides label based scalar lookups. You can also set using these indexers.

So I ran some samples:

## Setup

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from string import letters, lowercase, uppercase

lt = list(letters)
lc = list(lowercase)
uc = list(uppercase)

def gdf(rows, cols, seed=None):
    """rows and cols are what you'd pass
    to pd.MultiIndex.from_product()"""
    gmi = pd.MultiIndex.from_product
    df = pd.DataFrame(index=gmi(rows), columns=gmi(cols))
    np.random.seed(seed)
    df.iloc[:, :] = np.random.rand(*df.shape)
    return df

seed = [3, 1415]
df = gdf([lc, uc], [lc, uc], seed)

print df.head().T.head().T
```

`df` looks like:

```
            a                                        
            A         B         C         D         E
a A  0.444939  0.407554  0.460148  0.465239  0.462691
  B  0.032746  0.485650  0.503892  0.351520  0.061569
  C  0.777350  0.047677  0.250667  0.602878  0.570528
  D  0.927783  0.653868  0.381103  0.959544  0.033253
  E  0.191985  0.304597  0.195106  0.370921  0.631576
```

Lets use `.at` and `.loc` and ensure I get the same thing

```
print "using .loc", df.loc[('a', 'A'), ('c', 'C')]
print "using .at ", df.at[('a', 'A'), ('c', 'C')]

using .loc 0.37374090276
using .at  0.37374090276
```

Test speed using `.loc`

```
%%timeit
df.loc[('a', 'A'), ('c', 'C')]

10000 loops, best of 3: 180 µs per loop
```

Test speed using `.at`

```
%%timeit
df.at[('a', 'A'), ('c', 'C')]

The slowest run took 6.11 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 8 µs per loop
```

This looks to be a huge speed increase.  Even at the caching stage `6.11 * 8` is a lot faster than `180`

## Question

What are the limitations of `.at`?  I'm motivated to use it.  The documentation says it's similar to `.loc` but it doesn't behave similarly.  Example:

```
# small df
sdf = gdf([lc[:2]], [uc[:2]], seed)

print sdf.loc[:, :]

          A         B
a  0.444939  0.407554
b  0.460148  0.465239
```

where as `print sdf.at[:, :]` results in `TypeError: unhashable type`

So obviously not the same even if the intent is to be similar.

That said, who can provide guidance on what can and cannot be done with the `.at` method?

Comment: FYI: python3 version of letters, lowercase and uppercase constant are prepended with ascii_ https://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/library/string.html#string-constants

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Update: [`df.get_value`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.get_value.html) is deprecated as of version 0.21.0. Using `df.at` or `df.iat` is the recommended method going forward.

---

`df.at` can only access a single value at a time.

`df.loc` can select multiple rows and/or columns.

Note that there is also [`df.get_value`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.get_value.html), which may be even quicker at accessing single values:

```
In [25]: %timeit df.loc[('a', 'A'), ('c', 'C')]
10000 loops, best of 3: 187 µs per loop

In [26]: %timeit df.at[('a', 'A'), ('c', 'C')]
100000 loops, best of 3: 8.33 µs per loop

In [35]: %timeit df.get_value(('a', 'A'), ('c', 'C'))
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.62 µs per loop
```

---

Under the hood, `df.at[...]`  [calls `df.get_value`](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/indexing.py#L1649), but it also does [some type checking](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/indexing.py#L1678) on the keys.

Comment: Please note that `get_value` is deprecated since version 0.21.0.

Comment: does this deprecation imply that we should use .loc instead of .at ?

Comment: No, it doesn’t imply that. at is faster than loc but only works on individual cells. loc can work with arrays of cells

Comment: You may want to test this again. There is not much difference anymore.

%timeit df.at[100, ['A']] = 10                                         
661 µs ± 2.91 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit df.loc[100, ['A']] = 10                                        
645 µs ± 3.21 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

Comment: I'm finding that df.at does indeed access multiple rows if there are duplicated index values.

Answer (score 57):

As you asked about the limitations of `.at`, here is one thing I recently ran into (using pandas 0.22). Let's use the example from [the documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.at.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 2, 3], [0, 4, 1], [10, 20, 30]], index=[4, 5, 6], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
df2 = df.copy()

    A   B   C
4   0   2   3
5   0   4   1
6  10  20  30
```

If I now do

```
df.at[4, 'B'] = 100
```

the result looks as expected

```
    A    B   C
4   0  100   3
5   0    4   1
6  10   20  30
```

However, when I try to do

```
 df.at[4, 'C'] = 10.05
```

**it seems that `.at` tries to conserve the datatype (here: `int`)**:

```
    A    B   C
4   0  100  10
5   0    4   1
6  10   20  30
```

That seems to be a difference to `.loc`:

```
df2.loc[4, 'C'] = 10.05
```

yields the desired

```
    A   B      C
4   0   2  10.05
5   0   4   1.00
6  10  20  30.00
```

The risky thing in the example above is that it happens silently (the conversion from `float` to `int`). When one tries the same with strings it will throw an error:

```
df.at[5, 'A'] = 'a_string'
```

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a_string'

It will work, however, if one uses a string on which `int()` actually works as noted by @n1k31t4 in the comments, e.g.

```
df.at[5, 'A'] = '123'

     A   B   C
4    0   2   3
5  123   4   1
6   10  20  30
```

Comment: Good point!  I've been debating where I should bring this up.

Comment: @piRSquared: Yes, would be good if this was documented anywhere (might have overlooked it though and I should try on 0.23).

Comment: Happens on 0.23 as well.  Try `df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]]), df.at[0, 1] = 'a'`

Comment: Thank you for this, it definitely does try to preserve the numeric datatype. I was trying `df.at[1, 'test'] = 'string'` and it wasn't working. `.loc` fixed the problem

Comment: So if you pass it anything that `int()` is able to consume, it will work... meaning you could do: `df.at[5, "A"] = "123"` and it would assign the string, converting it to int along the way.

Comment: @n1k31t4: Thanks for the comment and sorry for the very late reply. You are correct; I added your example to the answer.

Answer (score 12):

Adding to the above, Pandas [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html) for the `at` function states:

> Access a single value for a row/column label pair.
>
> Similar to loc, in that both provide label-based lookups. Use at if
> you only need to get or set a single value in a DataFrame or Series.

For setting data `loc` and `at` are similar, for example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3], 'B': [11,22,33]}, index=[0,0,1])
```

Both `loc` and `at` will produce the same result

```
df.at[0, 'A'] = [101,102]
df.loc[0, 'A'] = [101,102]

    A   B
0   101 11
0   102 22
1   3   33

df.at[0, 'A'] = 103
df.loc[0, 'A'] = 103

    A   B
0   103 11
0   103 22
1   3   33
```

Also, for accessing a single value, both are the same

```
df.loc[1, 'A']   # returns a single value (<class 'numpy.int64'>)
df.at[1, 'A']    # returns a single value (<class 'numpy.int64'>)

3
```

However, when matching multiple values, `loc` will return a group of rows/cols from the DataFrame while `at` will return an array of values

```
df.loc[0, 'A']  # returns a Series (<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>)

0    103
0    103
Name: A, dtype: int64

df.at[0, 'A']   # returns array of values (<class 'numpy.ndarray'>)

array([103, 103])
```

And more so, `loc` can be used to match a group of row/cols and can be given only an index, while `at` must receive the column

```
df.loc[0]  # returns a DataFrame view (<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>)

    A   B
0   103 11
0   103 22


# df.at[0]  # ERROR: must receive column
```

Comment: The error when you try to query `df.at[0]` where 0 is not unique has changed to `ValueError: Invalid call for scalar access (getting)!`. It's not the most idiomatic error, but this behavior may be desired if you expected the index to be unique.

Answer (score 5):

`.at` is an optimized data access method compared to `.loc` .

`.loc` of a data frame selects all the elements located by indexed_rows and labeled_columns as given in its argument. Instead, `.at` selects particular element of a data frame positioned at the given indexed_row and labeled_column.

Also, `.at` takes one row and one column as input argument, whereas `.loc` may take multiple rows and columns. Output using `.at` is a single element and using `.loc` maybe a Series or a DataFrame.

Comment: Returning single value is not the case always. It returns array of values if the provided index is used multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

Another limitation of `.at` is that `.loc` accept other inputs (in exchange for index), such as conditions, whereas `.at` does not :

```
> df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], 
                   [0, 0],
                   ], 
                   columns=["A", "B"])

> df["A"] > 0 # is a pd.Series of bool values

> df.loc[df["A"] > 0, "B"] # provides the first line in this example

> df.at[df["A"] > 0, "B"] # using .at will raise InvalidIndexError
```