# How do I access a numpy array as quickly as a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I ran a comparison of several ways to access data in a `DataFrame`.  See results below.  The quickest access was from using the `get_value` method on a `DataFrame`.  I was referred to this on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37216485/pandas-at-versus-loc).

What I was surprised by is that the access via `get_value` is quicker than accessing via the underlying numpy object `df.values`.

#### Question

My question is, is there a way to access elements of a numpy array as quickly as I can access a pandas dataframe via `get_value`?

#### Setup

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(16).reshape(4, 4))
```

#### Testing

```
%%timeit
df.iloc[2, 2]
```

> 10000 loops, best of 3: 108 µs per loop

```
%%timeit
df.values[2, 2]
```

> The slowest run took 5.42 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
>   100000 loops, best of 3: 8.02 µs per loop

```
%%timeit
df.iat[2, 2]
```

> The slowest run took 4.96 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
>   100000 loops, best of 3: 9.85 µs per loop

```
%%timeit
df.get_value(2, 2)
```

> The slowest run took 19.29 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
>   100000 loops, best of 3: 3.57 µs per loop

Comment: To whom ever down voted this question, I'd appreciate some feedback as to why. Thanks

Comment: If your bottleneck is single-element access, then you should be accessing more than one element at a time

Comment: Also, you may want to check that `x = df.values; %timeit x[2,2]` gives similar results - perhaps `values` is not an attribute but a `property`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`iloc` is pretty general, accepting slices and lists as well as simple integers.  In the case above, where you have simple integer indexing, pandas first determines that it is a valid integer, then it converts the request to an `iat` index, so clearly it will be much slower.  `iat` eventually resolves down to a call to `get_value`, so naturally a direct call to `get_value` is going to be fast.  `get_value` itself is cached, so micro-benchmarks like these may not reflect performance in real code.

`df.values` does return an ndarray, but only after checking that it is a single contiguous block.  This requires a few lookups and tests so it is a little slower than retrieving the value from the cache.

We can defeat the caching by creating a new data frame every time.  This shows that `values` accessor is fastest, at least for data of a uniform type:

```
In [111]: %timeit df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(16).reshape(4, 4))
10000 loops, best of 3: 186 µs per loop

In [112]: %timeit df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(16).reshape(4, 4)); df.values[2,2]
1000 loops, best of 3: 200 µs per loop

In [113]: %timeit df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(16).reshape(4, 4)); df.get_value(2,2)
1000 loops, best of 3: 309 µs per loop

In [114]: %timeit df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(16).reshape(4, 4)); df.iat[2,2]
1000 loops, best of 3: 308 µs per loop

In [115]: %timeit df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(16).reshape(4, 4)); df.iloc[2,2]
1000 loops, best of 3: 420 µs per loop

In [116]: %timeit df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(16).reshape(4, 4)); df.ix[2,2]
1000 loops, best of 3: 316 µs per loop
```

The code claims that `ix` is the most general, and so should be in theory be slower than `iloc`; it may be that your particular test favours `ix` but other tests may favour `iloc` just because of the order of the tests needed to identify the index as a scalar index.

Comment: In addition to providing a very good answer, I wanted to thank you for providing good technique in decoupling caching from performance checking.  Running a df creation as a benchmark followed by tests where df is created from scratch is perfect for determining the time to use each method for look up in live code.