# Dynamically Add Rows to DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have an empty dataframe, already set up with columns, but no rows. I'm scraping some data from the web so let's say I need to add an index `'2176'` to the empty dataframe. How could I automatically add this row to the database when I try to assign it? Is this even pandas purpose or should I use something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['foo1','foo2'])

df.loc[2176,'foo1'] = 'my_value'
```

df is then:

```
        foo1        foo2
2176    my_value    NaN
```

Comment: more details:
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/2801#issuecomment-17644076

Answer (score 10):

As an alternative to `.loc`, you might want to consider [`at`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.at.html). Using @NickBraunagel's example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['foo1','foo2'])
```

Then

```
df.at['2716', 'foo1'] = 10
```

yields

```
     foo1 foo2
2716   10  NaN
```

Timings are quite different:

```
# @NickBraunagel's solution
%timeit df.loc['2716', 'foo1'] = 10
1000 loops, best of 3: 212 µs per loop

# the at solution
%timeit df.at['2716', 'foo1'] = 10
100000 loops, best of 3: 12.5 µs per loop
```

If you want to add several column entries at the same time, you can do:

```
d = {'foo1': 20, 'foo2': 10}
df.at['1234', :] = d
```

yielding

```
     foo1 foo2
2716   10  NaN
1234   20   10
```

However, make sure to always add the same datatype to avoid errors or other undesired effects as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50760615/1534017).

Comment: Good call, assuming you're only updating one value/cell at a time (which works for this example).  For reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37216587/4245462

Comment: @NickBraunagel: I guess this assumption is valid as OP was talking about single rows. Thanks for the reference!