# df.at with multiindex vs df.loc

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a question about the differences between `df.loc` and `df.at` with respect to dataframes with a MultiIndex.  I've been looking at a few wonderful resources from stackoverflow but it doesn't seem to shed on light on my issue.  This one in particular... [pandas .at versus .loc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37216485/pandas-at-versus-loc) (or at least I do not fully understand what is being displayed here).

Per the pandas documentation, https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/generated/pandas.DataFrame.at.html, `df.at` is supposed to return singular values, and its faster than `df.loc`, so i'm inclined to want to use `df.at`.  Let me show my confusion as it applies to using `df.at` with a MultiIndex.

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'field1':['foo']*6, 'field2':['bar']*6, 'field3': 
['a','a','b','b','b','c'],'value1':[0.4,0.5,0.4,0.7,.9,.4],'value2': 
[4000,4000,9000,9000,9000,10000]}, index=range(6))

df
Out[329]: 
  field1 field2 field3  value1  value2
0    foo    bar      a     0.4    4000
1    foo    bar      a     0.5    4000
2    foo    bar      b     0.4    9000
3    foo    bar      b     0.7    9000
4    foo    bar      b     0.9    9000
5    foo    bar      c     0.4   10000
```

I'd like to access this dataframe using a MultiIndex, so I'm doing the following:

```
df = df.set_index(['field1','field2','field3'])
```

So now I'd like to access `value1` in my `df` at `('foo','bar','c')` which is a singular value, and it errors.

```
df.at[('foo','bar','c'),'value1']
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-344-921b8b658a49>", line 1, in <module>
    df.at[('foo','bar','c'),'value1']

  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1610, 
in __getitem__
    return self.obj.get_value(*key, takeable=self._takeable)

  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1836, in 
get_value
    return engine.get_value(series.get_values(), index)

  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 103, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value 
(pandas\index.c:3234)

  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 111, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value 
(pandas\index.c:2931)

  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 152, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc 
(pandas\index.c:3830)

  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 170, in 
pandas.index.IndexEngine._get_loc_duplicates (pandas\index.c:4154)

TypeError: only integer arrays with one element can be converted to an index
```

I'm assuming this is returning a series object, which cannot be expressed a single value?  That is just my assumption given the output with `df.loc`.

```
df.loc[('foo','bar','c')]['value1']
 Out[345]: 
field1  field2  field3
foo     bar     c         0.4
Name: value1, dtype: float64
```

Now if I wasn't using a MultiIndex, I assume this issue does not arise...

Is there anyway around this, or I am clearly missing something?  Thank you

Comment: upvoted, it is a well-written question.

Comment: I can't reproduce this with Pandas 0.22.  Interestingly, `df.at[('foo', 'bar', 'a'), 'value1']` returns `array([ 0.4,  0.5])`.

Comment: Hmmm.  I'm using pandas 0.18, maybe this has been fixed?

Comment: Seconding cannot repeat in 0.22.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
# setting multiindex
df = df.set_index(['field1','field2','field3'])
```

Now when you use `df.at` like this: `df.at[('foo','bar','c')]['value1']`, you will get the desired result:

```
field1  field2  field3
foo     bar     c         0.4
Name: value1, dtype: float64
```

According to my attempts you probably didn't query the dataframe using `at` correctly.