# Returna value in Pandas by index row number and column name?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DF where the index is equal strings.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 2, 3], [0, 4, 1], [10, 20, 30]],

                  index=['a', 'a', 'a'], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
>>> df
    A   B   C
a   0   2   3
a   0   4   1
a  10  20  30
```

Let's say I am trying to access the value in col 'B' at the first row. I am using something like this:

```
>>> df.iloc[0]['B']
2
```

Reading the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37216485/pandas-at-versus-loc/62270412#62270412) it seems .at is recommended to be used for efficiency. Is there any better way in my example to return the value by the index row number and column name?

Comment: If you are doing once, it shouldn't be matter. If you are trying to do so repeatedly, remember that it is not recommended to do so :D

Comment: Why don't you give `df.iloc[0,1]` Using iloc is much better as you can use the index value

Comment: @QuangHoang Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, I have to do it in a loop. what is your suggestion?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any suggestions. My point is that you can try to find a vectorized solution to access all needed elements without a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `iat` with `get_indexer`

```
df.iat[0,df.columns.get_indexer(['B'])[0]]
Out[124]: 2
```