# Setting With Copy but I'm using .iloc and have no chain commands, why?

Tags: pandas

So I am doing this super simple program and it's returning a set with copy warning. I'm using iloc.

My goal is to check if the values in check if the value is a null and replace it with a tuple with 3 None values. It does work, but I'd like to avoid the copy warning.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[None,1, 2], 'b':[None, (1,2,3), (3,4, 5)]}) 

    a   b
0   NaN None
1   1.0 (1, 2, 3)
2   2.0 (3, 4, 5)


if pd.isna(df['b'].iloc[0]):
        df['b'].iloc[0] = (None, None, None)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `at` instead of `iloc`, but note that `at` can only work on one cell at a time ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37216485/pandas-at-versus-loc)).

```
if pd.isna(df['b'][0]):
    df.at[0,'b'] = (None, None, None)
print(df)
```

```
     a                   b
0  NaN  (None, None, None)
1  1.0           (1, 2, 3)
2  2.0           (3, 4, 5)
```

And you can check that it still added this as a tuple like your other row entries in `b`:

```
print(df.explode('b'))
```

```
     a     b
0  NaN  None
0  NaN  None
0  NaN  None
1  1.0     1
1  1.0     2
1  1.0     3
2  2.0     3
2  2.0     4
2  2.0     5
```

Comment: That's fine I only want it done on the first row of my column

Comment: @David54321 Please accept this answer if it resolves your question.