# pandas dataframe.at for a whole series

Tags: python, pandas

How can I convert the following code without using the loop, using pythonic pandas :

```py
import pandas as pd

xls = pd.ExcelFile('...')
df_1 = pd.read_excel(xls, '...')
df_2 = pd.read_excel(xls, '...')

df_1_len = len(df_1)
results = np.empty(df_1_len)
for idx in range(df_1_len):
    results[idx] = df_2.at[df_1['x'][idx], df_1['y'][idx]]
```

`df_1` looks like :

| x | y |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 2 | a |
| 2 | b |
| ... | ... |

`df_2` looks like :

|  | 1 | 2 | .. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | val(1,a) | val(2,a) | .. |
| b | val(1,n) | val(2,a) | .. |
| ... | ... | ... |  |

Comment: did you try `df_2.at[df_1['x'], df_1['y']]`?

Comment: @adirabargil yes, it throws `TypeError: unhashable type: 'Series'`

Comment: try `tolist()` each of them (sorry i am not if front of conputer…)

Comment: it gives the same error with `'list'` instead of `'series'`

Comment: you should unstack df2, and then create multiIndex from the df1, imma llok into it on sunday if you wont be able to figure out how.

Answer (score 0):

did you try `df_2.loc[df_1['x'], df_1['y']]`? Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37216587/13657497) can help you understanding the difference between `at` and `loc`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However it's not equivalent to the query I did. My result is a vector, yours is a matrix.