# Trying to update a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe (df) which looks like:

```
0   1                   2                       3
0   BBG.apples.S        BBG.XNGS.bananas.S      0
1   BBG.apples.S        BBG.XNGS.oranges.S      0
2   BBG.apples.S        BBG.XNGS.pairs.S        0
3   BBG.apples.S        BBG.XNGS.mango.S        0
4   BBG.apples.S        BBG.XNYS.mango.S        0
5   BBG.XNGS.bananas.S  BBG.XNGS.oranges.S      0
6   BBG.XNGS.bananas.S  BBG.XNGS.pairs.S        0
7   BBG.XNGS.bananas.S  BBG.XNGS.kiwi.S         0
8   BBG.XNGS.oranges.S  BBG.XNGS.pairs.S        0
9   BBG.XNGS.oranges.S  BBG.XNGS.kiwi.S         0
10  BBG.XNGS.peaches.S  BBG.XNGS.strawberrys.S  0
11  BBG.XNGS.peaches.S  BBG.XNGS.strawberrys.S  0
12  BBG.XNGS.peaches.S  BBG.XNGS.strawberrys.S  0
13  BBG.XNGS.peaches.S  BBG.XNGS.kiwi.S         0
```

I am trying to update a value (first row, third column) in the dataframe using:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():

        status = row[3]

        if int(status) == 0:

            df[index]['3'] = 1
```

but when I print the dataframe out it remains unchanged.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `iterrows()` only returns a single generator, `index,row` are two values. What value do you want to update? (`df[index]['3']` is supposed to represent what row and what column?)

Comment: Are you sure your column names are strings (`'3'`) and not integers? This could be causing confusion when you try to access the column. If in doubt, see what you get from print(df.columns).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your last line by:

```
df.at[index,'3'] = 1
```

Obviously as mentioned by others you're better off using a vectorized expression instead of iterating, especially for large dataframes.

Comment: Thanks Alex, if I amend slightly to df.at[index,3] = 1 it works a charm

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify a data frame by iterating like that. [See here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25478528/updating-value-in-iterrow-for-pandas)

If you only want to modify the element at [1, 3], you can access it directly:

```
df[1, 3] = 1
```

If you're trying to turn every `0` in column 3 to a `1`, try this:

```
df[df['3'] == 0] = 1
```

EDIT: In addition, the [docs for `iterrows`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) say that you'll often get a copy back, which is why the operation fails.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to update the third column for all rows based on the row having a certain value, as shown in your example code, then it would be much easier use the `where` method on the dataframe:

```
df.loc[:,'3'] = df['3'].where(df['3']!=0, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to update the row using .loc or .iloc (depend on your needs). 

 For example, in this case:

```
if int(status) == 0:
    df.iloc[index]['3']='1'
```