# Python Pandas Dataframe replace cell value by value of another cell of the same session

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, bigdata, data-analysis

I'm using Python Pandas Dataframe for Data Analyse of some logs.
I have a csv with something like:
number_items event_type ... ... ... session_id ... ... ...

My problem is that in my session there are different types of events, and only one of them has something for number_items. Or, numbers_items is what interests me.

So what I want to see is how each parameter of each event influences the number_items.

So, what I want to do is:
Copy the number_items of the event that has it (always the last one in the session) to all the other events of the session. Separate each event_type in a different Dataframe (to avoid a lot of nulls that exist only because the attribute doesn't correspond to the event) and analyse it.

I'm blocked at the first part

I tried something like this:

```
currentSession = '0'
currentItems = 0
for index, row in reversed(df.iterrows()) :
    if row['session_id'] == currentSession :
        row['number_items'] = currentItems
    else : 
        currentSession = row['session_id']
        currentItems = row['number_items']
```

Obviously, it's not working, I just wanted to show the idea.

I'm kind of new in Python, so I would appreciate some help.

Thanks

edit: data sample [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gvRsoBmc61eSiFPeNafHBeGBiS6EbDw18_JP16Xekd8/edit?usp=sharing)

For security reasons, I let only the relevant information

Comment: please post a minimal example of your input data and the expected output (its a bit hard to decipher from your text-description)

Comment: put a link to the data sample

Answer (score 0):

The rows you get back from iterrows are copies so they dont overwrite your original dataframe. Use another form of iterator that references the original dataframe.

see here [Updating value in iterrow for pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25478528/updating-value-in-iterrow-for-pandas)

(also im note entirely sure what it is you are trying to do but instinctively it seems very inefficient - i suspect there are natural pandas methods which might do what you trying to achieve in one or two lines, look up the where() method)

Comment: even reversed doesn't work well, I get error.
I was wondering if there is not a better method than to iterate.
Something to give all the cells of the session the value of cell of the event x if it exists, 0 if not

Comment: reversed only works if the iterator has a __reversed__() method or supports the procedure, which a pandas dataframe may or may not do. Sounds like it doesnt.