# How to remove a portion of a string with variable length

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a DataFrame in which one column is rows of strings that look like:

```
Received value 126;AOC;H3498XX from 602
Received value 101;KYL;0IMMM0432 from 229
```

I want to drop (or replace with nothing) the part after the second semicolon so that it looks like

```
Received value 126;AOC; from 602
```

But this part I want to drop will have varying and unpredictable lengths (always combinations of A-Z and 0-9).  The semicolons and froms will always be there for reference.

I'm trying to use regex by studying this link: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

```
import re
for row in df[‘column’]:
    row = re.sub(‘;[A-Z0-9] from’ , ‘; from’, row)
```

I think the [A-Z0-9] fails to incorporate the varying length aspect I want.

Comment: `print(s.replace(s.split(";",2)[-1].split()[0],''))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example using [`str.replace()`](https://www.pythoncentral.io/pythons-string-replace-method-replacing-python-strings/) with [`str.split()`](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/dictionary/python-split):

```
s = ['126;AOC;H3498XX from 602', '101;KYL;0IMMM0432 from 229']

for elem in s:
    print(elem.replace(elem.split(";",2)[-1].split()[0],''))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
126;AOC; from 602
101;KYL; from 229
```

**EDIT**:

The same would work with the following example as well:

```
s = ['Received value 126;AOC;H3498XX from 602', 'Received value 101;KYL;0IMMM0432 from 229']

for elem in s:
    print(elem.replace(elem.split(";",2)[-1].split()[0],''))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
Received value 126;AOC; from 602
Received value 101;KYL; from 229
```

Comment: This works perfectly when I use print(), but I want the output to remain in the column of my data frame.  When I try for elem in s: s['column'] = elem.replace.... it doesn't give me the expected output.  Do you know how to keep the output within the column of that dataframe?

Comment: @EricN. you could iterate through the desired rows and replace the values: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25478528/updating-value-in-iterrow-for-pandas

Answer (score 1):

Use pattern `(Received value \d+;[A-Z]+;)\w+(\s.*?)`

**Ex:**

```
import re

s = ["Received value 126;AOC;H3498XX from 602", "Received value 101;KYL;0IMMM0432 from 229"]

for i in s:
    print( re.sub(r"(Received value \d+;[A-Z]+;)\w+(\s.*?)", r"\1", i) )
```

**Output:**

```
Received value 126;AOC;from 602
Received value 101;KYL;from 229
```