# Converting datetime with different time-zone to date in specific date

Tags: python, pandas

Property to store most recent won deal stores information in rather odd format. The data is in datetime format with different timezones.

**I'm getting the following errors:**

"If tzaware, these values represent unix timestamps, so we" and "ValueError: Array must be all same time zone"

When I try one of the following commands:

`pd.to_datetime(df1['properties__recent_deal_close_date__value']`)

and

```
df1['properties__recent_deal_close_date__value'].dt.tz_convert('Eruope/Berlin')
```

**I would like to convert data such as this:**

```
2018-11-16 11:32:51.285000+01:00    
2019-02-28 17:13:49.492000+01:00    
2018-08-29 09:50:51+02:00
```

**To this:**

```
2019-11-16
2019-02-28
2018-08-29
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`dparser`](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```
import dateutil.parser as dparser

dt_1 = "2018-11-16 11:32:51.285000+01:00"
dt_2 = "2019-02-28 17:13:49.492000+01:00"
dt_3 = "2018-08-29 09:50:51+02:00"

print("Date: {}".format(dparser.parse(dt_1,fuzzy=True).date()))
print("Date: {}".format(dparser.parse(dt_2,fuzzy=True).date()))
print("Date: {}".format(dparser.parse(dt_3,fuzzy=True).date()))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
Date: 2018-11-16
Date: 2019-02-28
Date: 2018-08-29
```

Comment: Thanks! I just need to figure it out how to iterate through all the rows.

Comment: @MatijaŽiberna `for index, row in df.iterrows():`?

Comment: `for index, row in df1.iterrows():
        row['properties__recent_deal_close_date__value'] = 
dparser.parse(row,fuzzy=True).date()`


This is what I've tried. I've received the following error:
`TypeError: Parser must be a string or character stream, not Series`

Comment: Try: `for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    print(dparser.parse(row['properties__recent_deal_close_date__value'],fuzzy=True).date())`

Comment: Thanks, but still same error persists: `TypeError: Parser must be a string or character stream, not datetime`

Comment: That is a different error, just convert it to string: `for index, row in df1.iterrows(): print(dparser.parse(str(row['properties__recent_deal_close_date__value']),fuzzy=True).date())`

Comment: Got answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25478528/updating-value-in-iterrow-for-pandas