# For loop not saving changes made in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have two excel files **file1.xlsx** and **file2.xlsx**. The data present in **file1** is manually entered data (has only numerical data) and the data present is **file2** is processed data. Processing done are removing strings and removing white spaces, to convert into numerical. For an instance, "**2.123 456 ab**" is converted to "**2.123456**". Here "**ab**" is removed and "**white spaces**" are also removed.

Now, I am iterating over the dataframe using " **for index, row in df.iterrows( ):**" and based on some "**if-conditions**", making some changes in the dataframe using **row["column2"]=0** in the for-loop.

The changes made in file1 dataframe is happening outside the for-loop but for the file2, the changes made in the for-loop are not getting reflected outside the for-loop.

**Code used for removing spaces :**

```
 df["column1"]= df["column1"].apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'(\d)\s+(\d)' , r'\1', x))
```

or

```
df["column1"]= df["column1"].apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'(\d)\s+(\d)' , r'\1\2', x))
```

**code used for removing string:**

```
df["column1"] = df["column1"].replace({"ab":""}, regex =True).astype(float)
```

Is there anything related to strings, because of which updates are not reflected in file2 ?

Can someone please help

Advance thankyou

```
Code:
import pandas as pd
import re
file = "file2.xlsx"
df = pd.read_excel(file)
df["column2"]=1
df["column1"]   = df["column1"].apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'(\d)\s+(\d)', r'\1', x))
df["column1"] = df["column1"].replace({"ab":""}, regex=True).astype(float)
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if(row["column1"]==100):
        row["column2"]=0
print(df)
df.to_excel("output.xlsx", index =False)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "updates are not reflected in file2"?  Could you please post your full code, including this for loop?

Comment: In the iteration, row["coulmn2"] = 0 is the change that I have made and when I print dataframe after for-loop, the value in column2 for that particular row is still "1" and not "0"

Comment: Please post your full code (at least the parts that are relevant).

Comment: If the problem is with modifying column data during `iterrows` perhaps this can help: [Updating value in iterrow for pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25478528/updating-value-in-iterrow-for-pandas)

Comment: @Iguananaut I have added the code

Comment: @Iguananaut The link has helped. Thankyou