# pandas change values in dataframe with iterrows()?

Tags: python, pandas

I am experimenting with "flaging" some data with a `1` or `0` in a separated df column based on a condition, but could use some tips...

***EDIT***, *this question is NOT looking up data in a dataframe but is attempting to look for a solution modify values in the dataframe for each row based on row conditions.*

Made up data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


rows,cols = 8760,3
data = np.random.rand(rows,cols) 
tidx = pd.date_range('2019-01-01', periods=rows, freq='1T') 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['cooling_sig','heating_sig','economizer_sig'], index=tidx)
```

This is some extra parameters and columns for my application:

```
# params for air handling unit (ahu)
ahu_min_oa = .2

# make columns out of params
df['ahu_min_oa'] = ahu_min_oa
df['heating_mode'] = 0
df['econ_mode'] = 0
df['econ+mech_cooling'] = 0
df['mech_cooling'] = 0
```

A function to process the data but it doesn't work. Any better practices greatly appreciated other than hammering through each row of the dataframe. I am trying "flag" a mode with a value of `1` based on a condition. For example, for each row in the data the `heating_mode` would be True or `1` if the `heating_sig` is greater than zero.

```
def data_preprocess(dataframe):
    
    for index, row in dataframe.iterrows():
        
        # OS1, the AHU is heating
        if row.heating_sig > 0:
            row['heating_mode'] = 1

        # OS2, the AHU is using free cooling only
        if row.economizer_sig > row.ahu_min_oa and row.cooling_sig == 0:
            row['econ_mode'] = 1

        # OS3, the AHU is using free and mechanical cooling
        if row.economizer_sig > row.ahu_min_oa and row.cooling_sig > 0:
            row['econ+mech_cooling'] = 1

        # OS4, the AHU is using mechanical cooling only
        if row.economizer_sig <= row.ahu_min_oa and row.cooling_sig > 0:
            row['mech_cooling'] = 1

        return dataframe
```

Sorry probably sort of a strange application and question but thanks for any tips. My attempt at Flagging some data isnt working, all of the `value_counts()` are zero.

```
df['heating_mode'].value_counts()
df['mech_cooling'].value_counts()
df['econ_mode'].value_counts()
df['econ+mech_cooling'].value_counts()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Updating value in iterrow for pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25478528/updating-value-in-iterrow-for-pandas)

Comment: The real question is why do you need iterrows? This will likely be more efficient to use vectorial code

Comment: Would you have any tips to look at other than iterrows? Not a lot of wisdom here !

Comment: For example `df['heating_mode'] = df['heating_sig'].gt(0).astype(int)`.

Comment: Then `df['econ_mode'] = df['econimizer_sig'].gt(df['ahu_min_oa']) & df['cooling_sig'].eq(0)`, and so on...

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to (and shouldn't) iterate over your DataFrame.

Instead, try:

```
df.loc[df["heating_sig"].eq(1), "heating_mode"] = 1
df.loc[df["economizer_sig"].gt(df["ahu_min_oa"]) & df["cooling_sig"].eq(0), "econ_mode"] = 1
df.loc[df["economizer_sig"].gt(df["ahu_min_oa"]) & df["cooling_sig"].gt(0), "econ+mech_cooling"] = 1
df.loc[df["economizer_sig"].le(df["ahu_min_oa"]) & df["cooling_sig"].gt(0), "mech_cooling"] = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be more efficient ways of doing the same, but if you really need to use iterrows(), then follow the following approach:

```
def data_preprocess(dataframe):
    for index, row in dataframe.iterrows():
        # OS1, the AHU is heating
        if row.heating_sig > 0:
            dataframe.at[index, 'heating_mode'] = 1

        # OS2, the AHU is using free cooling only
        if row.economizer_sig > row.ahu_min_oa and row.cooling_sig == 0:
            dataframe.at[index, 'econ_mode'] = 1

        # OS3, the AHU is using free and mechanical cooling
        if row.economizer_sig > row.ahu_min_oa and row.cooling_sig > 0:
            dataframe.at[index, 'econ+mech_cooling'] = 1

        # OS4, the AHU is using mechanical cooling only
        if row.economizer_sig <= row.ahu_min_oa and row.cooling_sig > 0:
            dataframe.at[index, 'mech_cooling'] = 1

    return dataframe
```